# Equation for excel cell please

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Could anyone help me to create an equation for the following request in my Excel table?

Column `B` contains the instruction to find which number to select within the cell next to it in Column `C`.

For example, if column `B` contains the number `12`, so "1" and "2" (it contains 2 instructions) it means: In the cell next to it, count 1 times right, count 2 times left (hence number 12)
[image: Request for column A]

This would be the result:
[image: Result for column A]

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please note that superuser.com is not a free script/code/homework writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code/calculations you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How to Ask](https://superuser.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: This question should include more details and clarify the problem.

Comment: *"... count 1 times right, count 2 times left"* can you explain a bit clearer what this means? I don't see how this matches your result (for example, in the first row how do you count two left after counting one right only? One to the right is a number 1 but then going back 2 would be before the start. Or in row 4 if you count 6 time going to the right there is a 3)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the idea here is to figuratively move the cursor from the left of the input `n` steps to the right (steps == 1st digit of your instruction), then `n` steps to the left (steps == 2nd digit of your instruction). When the edge of the input is reached, the cursor would jump back to the front/end of the input respectively.

This would also assume that if there is just a single instruction (e.g.: `6`) that this would mean this is the instruction that would take the cursur to the right.

[image]

Formula in `A1`:

```
=LET(a,B1:B6&IF(LEN(B1:B6)=1,0,""),b,C1:C6,MID(b,MOD(LEFT(a)-RIGHT(a)+LEN(b),LEN(b))+1,1))
```

**Note** that your method of operation only works if you have single digit instructions. It is unclear how you'd operate if an instruction would be larger then 9.